# Meteor, Session values and reactivity

Tags: session, meteor

I recall reading somewhere that one of the nice things about Session variables in Meteor was that when you changed a Session variable, anywhere that you used Session.get for that variable would react to the new value. I have a form where if the user cancels out of adding a new record I set that Session variable back to the last document in the collection, #2 in my case, but the form stays on the never added new record #3.

Here is my basic form;

```
<template name="transactions">
<form id="trx_form">
{{#each currentVal}}
  Trx No. <input type="text" value="{{trx_num}}" id="trx_num" readonly>
  Amount: <input type="text" value="{{trx_amount}}" id="trx_amount">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" id="save_trx">
  <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancel_trx">
{{/each}}
</form>
</template>
```

The Session variable gets set to the last record in the collection in a seperate navigation form `Session.set('trx_DB_currentID', trx_DB_currentID)`

This is what gets the values of that document;

```
Template.transactions.currentVal = function() {
var currValues = {trx_num: '', trx_amount: '''};
var trxCursor = trx.find({"_id": Session.get('trx_DB_currentID')});
trxCursor.forEach( function(rec) {
    currValues.trx_num = trx.find({"userID": Meteor.userId()}).count(); 
    currValues.trx_amount = rec.trx_amount;
});
var array = [];
array[0] = currValues;
return array;
};
```

Everything up to this point works fine. Here is the event for clicking the cancel button;

```
'click #cancel_trx': function(theEvent, theTemplate) {
// Change trx_DB_currentID to last record
var trxCursor = trx.find({"userID": Meteor.userId(), 'trx_num': trx.find({"userID": Meteor.userId()}).count()});
trxCursor.forEach( function(rec) {
    Session.set('trx_DB_currentID', rec._id);   
});
}
```

I can see in the console that `trx_DB_currentID` is indeed set to the id for record #2 but the form still shows a blank record #3. If I click go back one record on my navigation form it brings up record #1. So why doesn't my form react to `trx_DB_currentID` being set to record #2?

Comment: Perhaps irrelevant to your question, but I'm not sure I quite understand the currentVal helper. Why are you using forEach and an array for a cursor that will always return one item (you're querying by _id, which is unique)? Seems to me like findOne would work better there, and you can just access `trxCursor.trx_amount` directly.

Comment: Also, it looks like the reason you always see #1 (not #2) when you click 'cancel_trx' is that you are iterating over the trxCursor, i.e the Session.set() will keep on overriding the previous value and always return the last value in the cursor.

Comment: mark, After beginning and canceling a third record I can see that `Session.get('trx_DB_currentID')` does indeed contain the Id for record #2 but the empty form that was started is still showing.